# How to build stdlib a file in golang?

Tags: go

I want to debug standard library in go language, so I add some log to a standard library file, but this does not make any difference, I think I should rebuild the .a file, how can I do this?

```
$ go version
go version go1.8.1 darwin/amd64

$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/usr/local/go1.8.1/bin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/bitstore/Projects/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go1.8.1"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go1.8.1/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/4r/62myx2852db5cdvrtqx63gl40000gn/T/go-build009034286=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"

$ go install -v text/scanner
output nothing

I install use environment variables
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go1.8.1
export GOBIN=$GOROOT/bin
export GOPATH=$HOME/Projects/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN:$GOPATH/bin

$ ls -la /usr/local/go1.8.1/src/text/scanner/scanner.go
-rw-r--r--  1 bitstore  staff  17545  4 24 22:19 /usr/local/go1.8.1/src/text/scanner/scanner.go
$ go install -v text/scanner
$ ls -la /usr/local/go1.8.1/pkg/darwin_amd64/text/scanner.a
-rw-r--r--@ 1 bitstore  staff  53838  4  8 00:54 /usr/local/go1.8.1/pkg/darwin_amd64/text/scanner.a
```

Comment: Did you run `go install packagename`? What package are you trying to build?

Comment: @JimB text/scanner, it's not in gopath, it's standard library in goroot

Comment: OK, but have you tried `go install text/scanner`? That's how you install any package. (Or you can just install Go from source, and use the same procedure)

Comment: Read https://golang.org/doc/install/source

Comment: @JimB yes , I tried this. But not help.

Answer (score 1):

The Go tools look at the source timestamps to see if installation is necessary. For example,

```
$ cd ~
$ touch /home/peter/go/src/text/scanner/scanner.go
$ go install -v text/scanner/
text/scanner
$ go install -v text/scanner/
$
```

`go install` looks in `$GOROOT` then `$GOPATH`.

What is your output from the `go version` and `go env` commands?

```
$ go version
go version devel +1737aef Mon Apr 24 12:37:49 2017 +0000 linux/amd64

$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/peter/gopath"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/peter/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/peter/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build148116572=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
$
```

How did you install Go?

Comment: 3ks for answering, I update the question with detailed information

Comment: You didn't `touch /usr/local/go1.8.1/src/text/scanner/scanner.go` before `go install -v text/scanner`.

Comment: i have touch it, but the .a file still seems not change, as i updated